# How to "switch user" under KDE without locking the current session?

Tags: kde, lock-screen

The family computer has 3 users (mom, dad and daughter). All 3 use KDE. Daughter is too young to deal with passwords, so she is a member of the nopasswdlogin group so she can log in without a password. However, when daughter is logged in and dad wants to use the computer, dad goes to "Switch User" and logs in to his account. When daughter wants to play again, she goes to "Switch User" to log back in to her account. She is then faced with a "This session is locked" dialog and prompted for a password.

The same thing happens when daughter is logged in and the computer goes to sleep. Upon waking up, her session is locked and she is prompted for a password.

How can I configure daughter's KDE account so that she is not prompted for a password when either switching back to her account or when the computer wakes up?

Comment: That is not a question of KDE, but of display manager. What display manager are you using? LightDM? SDDM?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using kde 4.9 In the System Settings (systemsettings), in the Hardware section, under Power Management, the Advanced Settings section has a checkbox for "Lock screen on resume" Remove the tick mark and hopefully the problem will be solved.

If you are using kde 4.5.3 Go into System Settings, and in System Administration at the bottom, select Login Screen. From there, go to the Convenience tab and enable passwordless logins for all the users on the system. Do not enable an autologin for any user. Then when you switch users, it should not ask for a password.

Hope this helps...

Comment: That does indeed work for when the computer goes to sleep and wakes up, thanks. However, when switching user from dad's account to daughter's, she is still faced with a session locked dialog.